# Is there such a thing as "finite" induction?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

I am not sure of the terminology that I am looking for, but I would like to use an inductive proof on the following type of structure. I have something of the form, for every $n \geq 2$ and for any $1 \leq d \leq n-1$, some property $P(n, d)$ is true. I chose to do induction on $d$ since it appears to make the proof simpler (fewer cases in the case-by-case analysis for my problem). So my base-case was $P(n, 1)$, then I showed that $P(n, d-1)$ implies $P(n, d)$ for any $2 \leq d \leq n-1$. Typically, induction has this "infinite domino effect", like in the proof that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$, but in my proof, this is not the case as the "domino effect" stops at $d = n-1$. Is this an okay thing to do? Do I still call this a proof by induction? Or does it have a different name?

Comment: It is just induction over a finite set, and it is fine.

Comment: there are two points of view on the induction : the inductive direction, where you start at $a_1$, and from $a_1$ you deduce $a_2$, from $a_2$ deduce $a_3$, etc. and the recursive direction : you start from $a_n$ what you want to prove, and you build a descending chain until you reach the base case $a_1$, and at this point you have proven that $a_n$ is true because at each step you stored that "if $a_{k}$, then $a_n$". see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it induction because nowhere in this proof is the fifth Peano axiom actually used. For given $n$, you can simply repeat the inductive step until you get to $d=n-1$ so you've exhausted every possibility.

Comment: Induction is valid for any set for which every subset has a "least" element  in some order in which every element has a "next" element. It is essentially a proof by contradiction. Assume the proposition is false for some element in the set (finite or infinite) and show that the assumption leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

If you have $n$ as a variable (not as a fixed constant like $n=30$) then I am quite sure (though I did to try to write down the details) that you can prove the full induction principle (for natural numbers) from the validity of your special induction principle.

From this point of view, I would really call it a proof by induction.

To see that your special induction principle is a special case of the general induction principle (for natural numbers) is simple: Given a natural number $n$, just apply the general induction principle to the property
$$``\text{$d\ge n$ or $P(n,d)$``}$$