# Using induction to prove a statement about a finite number of elements

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I want to confirm that I am correctly proving (formally) a statement about a finite number of elements using induction. I found this ([Is there such a thing as "finite" induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807724/is-there-such-a-thing-as-finite-induction)) post, but the most highly rated comment is simply: "*It is just induction over a finite set, and it is fine.*"

I believe this approach should be generalizable to any similarly structured claim...but for this post, I will prove the following statement:

> If $S_n(x)=x^n$, and $0 \leq k \leq n$, prove that $S_n^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$, where $S_n^{(k)}(x)$ denotes the $k$-th derivative of the function $S_n$ evaluated at $x$.

As a reminder, one can prove that for any constant $c$ and $n$, if $f(x)=c\cdot x^n $, then $f^{(1)}(x)=c\cdot n x^ {n-1} \dagger$

---

For some arbitrary $n$ and corresponding function $S_n$, where $S_n(x)=x^n$, let $\varphi(k)$ be defined as : $0 \leq k \leq n \rightarrow S_n^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$. Therefore, we want to apply the *classical* induction on the statement $\forall k \in \mathbb N \ [ \varphi(k)]$.

**Base Case**:

Let $k=0$. $S_n^{(0)}(x)=S^n(x)=x^n=\frac{n!}{(n-0)!}x^{n-0}$.

**Assumption for $k$**

For some $k \in \mathbb N$, assume $0 \leq k \leq n \rightarrow S_n^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$

**Prove for $k+1$**

Prove the following statement:

$ 0 \leq k+1 \leq n \rightarrow S_n^{(k+1)}(x)=\frac{n!}{\left(n-(k+1)\right)!}x^{n-(k+1)}$

Two cases: $\quad$ i) $k \geq n \quad$ ii) $0 \leq k \lt n$

Case 1)

If $k \geq n$, then $k+1 \gt n$. This makes our implication vacuously true.

Case 2)

If $0 \leq k \lt n$, then $0 \lt k+1 \leq n$. Let $S_n^{(k)}:=f(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$.

By $\dagger$,  $f^{(1)}=(n-k)\cdot\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k-1}=\frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!}x^{n-k-1}=\frac{n!}{\left(n-(k+1)\right)!}x^{n-(k+1)}$...and $f^{(1)}=S_n^{(k+1)}$

Thus, we have proven: $\forall k \in \mathbb N \ \left[ 0 \leq k \leq n \rightarrow S_n^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}\right]$.

---

As a side note, it is perhaps an error to describe these sorts of problems as a statement about "a finite number of elements". Given the outlined approach, it seems appropriate to say that this statement is really about *all* natural numbers...it's just that an infinite number of natural numbers satisfy the property vacuously (whereas a finite number of natural numbers satisfy the property non-vacuously).

Comment: Sure, if you use that perspective, then all finite induction is a special case of regular induction. You don't really gain anything from that perspective though.